# How to simulate CURL call in Postman?

Tags: curl, httprequest, postman

I have a Curl call that works from my linux machine:

```
curl -XGET --insecure https://1.2.3.4:9200/_cat/ -u admin:admin
```

How to simulate it in Postman?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This curl call is consisted by 4 parameters:

1. HTTP method is `GET` (`-X GET`). To simulate in Postman, choose `GET` (the default value) in the request panel.
2. HTTP request is proceeded even if certificate verification is failed (`--insecure`). To simulate in Postman, turn off "SSL certificate verification" in Postman preference. According to the [document](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/settings/), this only works in Postman native app.
3. URL is `https://1.2.3.4:9200/_cat/`. To simulate this, copy and paste it in the address bar of request panel.
4. Credential (`-u admin:admin`). To simulate this in Postman, configure it in the "Authorization" tab of request panel.

Here are some screenshot:

To simulate "GET https://1.2.3.4:9200/_cat/":

[image]

To simulate `--insecure`:

[image]

To simulate credential (take Basic auth for example, you can change to other types due to requirement):

[image]